# Sequelize model crahes on .get

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've got node7 and sequelize 4.2.

I'm trying to use model.get({ plain: true }) but it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: instance.get is not a function
at dataValues.(anonymous function).map.instance (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3116:64)
at Array.map (native)
at model.get (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3116:39)
at model.get (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3140:31)
at game.model.save.then (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\modules\coinflip.js:139:32)
at tryCatcher (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\Programming\NodeJS\ozzgame2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
```

The code:

```
                        game.model.save().then(() => {
                            currentGames[game.model.id] = game;

                            callback(null, {
                                roundInfo: game.model.get({ plain: true })   });
                        }, err => callback(err));
```

"game" is previously found in the object:

```
for(let currentGameKey in currentGames) {
        if(!currentGames.hasOwnProperty(currentGameKey)) continue;
        if(gameId == currentGameKey) {
            continuation(currentGames[currentGameKey], false);
            break;
        }
    }
```

What could it be?

Comment: Get is available only at the model instance, which is made  on top of data fetched from db, and not at the model level

Can you show where are u using get

Comment: Just added to the post above

Comment: Assuming game is a [model instance](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html) , you should be using game.save and game.get

Comment: Nope, game.model is a model instance, game is just an object containing model and other stuff.

Comment: Then save and get are not to be used there.
They are basically available only on the data which sequelize refers as model instance

Comment: I use them on game.model, not on "game".

Comment: I get that, But you can use save and get only on a instance object and not on a model. Check the docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html)

Comment: game.model is an instance, result of .save() promise is also instance.

Comment: but none of them work.

Comment: Can you do console.log(game.model) and show it here.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already got rid of it, but before I posted this question I logged it. It was an INSTANCE of the model.